# How to look up macros?

Tags: rust

How do you look up a macro in Rust?

E.g., I was reading the source code for [serde_json](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/src/serde_json/ser.rs.html#420-445) and encountered the macro `tri!`.

I ended up downloading the code and running spinning up VS Code. But this isn't always feasible. And sometimes it's a different version, etc. I should be able to read code without running it.

But this is only a specific example. How do you look up *any* macro in Rust, in any codebase"?

Comment: Because [this](https://doc.servo.org/src/serde_json/lib.rs.html#437-447) is the fourth result when I search the Internet for "Rust 'tri' macro".

Comment: I already found the answer. What I'm looking for is *how* to find the answer via the code, not randomly google searching. Not all libraries will be google-friendly. If you see a list of characters in a program, you should always be able to find out what they refer to. What is the general method?

Comment: If it's a macro that you're meant to use, it will be public and show up in the [`Macros` header](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/index.html#macros) as well as in the doc search results. If you're wanting to look up something internal, you're basically going to have to dig into the code, like you did here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros have different lookup rules than normal items. You can find details in the [Scoping, Exporting, and Importing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#scoping-exporting-and-importing) section for Macros by Example in the Rust Reference.

Basically there are two kinds of scopes to lookup macros:

- *path based scoping:* which is the same as normal item lookup where it can be imported by `use` statement or by path:

  ```
  use macros::a;
  a!();

  macros::b!();
  ```
- *textual scoping:* a non-path-qualified macro will first look at macro definitions in the current module *and all parent modules*. I think this is better shown with an example:

  ```
  mod a {
      macro_rules! macro_a { () => {};  }

      mod b {
          macro_rules! macro_b { () => {};  }

          mod c {
              macro_rules! macro_c { () => {};  }

              macro_a!(); // these all work
              macro_b!(); // without any
              macro_c!(); // explicit imports
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  This will work across files as well. However, keep in mind that macro definitions are ordered, meaning a macro defined after its use is not considered.

So when looking at source code, I generally search for macros in this order:

- Look in the current module for any `macro_rules!` definitions or matching import statements. This can get hairy if there are wild-card imports, but that's just how it goes sometimes; use your best judgement if the macro could be there.
- Look in the crate root (usually `main.rs` or `lib.rs`) for similar definitions or imports. This is because often crate-internal macros are designed to be used crate-wide, and following textual lookup above, any macro in the crate root is available everywhere. This is also the likely place where you'll find `#[macro_use]` definitions either for some internal `macros` module (as is the case with serde-json), or on `extern crate ...;` declarations (where they *must* be at the crate root).
- Then look in intermediate modules. I don't think I've ever had to do this personally, but its possible.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. Will the macros show up on doc.rs on the right hand side (where it says Traits, Macros, etc.)?

To be clear - the macro doesn't need to be declared "pub"?

Comment: @Test If the macro showed up in the docs you wouldn't have to scrounge around in the source code to find it. The docs will only show `pub` items (macros included) unless they were generated with `--document--private-items`.